# Autoplotter Python Library Integraton with Django Python Web framework

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have seen a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoTExfJG0mY&t=424s) Which is demonstrating the data analysis in the jupyter notebook cell, I am looking for the solution that how can i show the output of autoplotter which is python library in the django templates. Below is the code snippet of autoplotter which i have taken from its [official website](https://pypi.org/project/autoplotter/):

```
from autoplotter import run_app # Importing the autoplotter for GUI Based EDA
import pandas as pd # Importing Pandas to read csv

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ersaurabhverma/autoplotter/master/Data/data.csv") # Reading data

run_app(df,mode = "inline", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000) # Calling the autoplotter.run_app in inline mode

run_app(df,mode = "external", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000) # Calling the autoplotter.run_app in external mode
```

I am looking for that what is the output format of this command

> run_app (dataframe, host, port....)

how can I display its output in my django templates? so that a person could interact with his data through my launched website? Looking for any smart solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't run it under Django project because autoplotter uses Flask to serve the data and Flask can work only in the main thread of the main interpreter.

However, you can solve your problem using Docker. You will have a separate service that serves the autoplotter app and Django can have an `iframe` in HTML template that shows the content of the service.

**UPD:**
For the Docker - you can start with [this guide](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application). The only difference will be in your case is that **app.py** will contain only the call for a plotter:

```
if __name == '__main__':
    run_app(df, mode="external", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

And requirements.txt with autoplotter

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me on this, my second part of question was hat is the output format of run_app() function why we cannot render that output in HTML function in the python like this ---> df= pd.DataFrame(data)
    df1= df.tail(10)
    #s = df1.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
    mydic = {
        "df": df1.to_html()
    }
    return render(request, 'auth_home.html', context=mydic) , in this code we know the output that is pandas dataframe, similarly if we know the run_App output we directly render into templates of django. Need your further guideline please

Comment: One more  thing is there any useful link that can provide help for beginner to create service for python library like autoplotter ?

Comment: @Ehsan125 the problem is that autoplotter do not just generate some HTML, it runs Flask in any case (Which can't be executed from Django). 
You may try to replicate the logic under autoplotter.run_app inside Django to achieve the similar result. However, running it separately will be much easier

Comment: @Ehsan125 for Docker guide - see update in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, one more thing i want to ask the docker guide which you have provided I  also have to update the requiremnts.txt with autoplotter ? and i have also import this in app.y with this --> from autoplotter import run_app # Importing the autoplotter for GUI Based EDA ,     I am right?

Comment: setup(**setup_args, install_requires=install_requires), while installing the autoplotter it is giving the above error, i have put the autoplotter in the requirements.txt

Comment: @Ehsan125 yes. The concept of running an app in Docker is basically the same as running on your local machine except the machine is virtual and the code is inside the container. Maybe you need to check some basic Docker tutorials first